# List<T>.Insert Method affecting more than the one element calling the insert method

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a list of objects that contain a "sub" list of objects.
This list is based on calendar days and each calendar day has the day's date, some other properties, and a ***DayParts*** list property like:

```
Public Property DayParts As List(Of CalendarDayPart)
```

I am using the List(T).**Insert** Method to insert a manually created ***CalendarDayPart*** into the list ***DayParts*** for one specific day.

### THE PROBLEM

The insert method is inserting the manually created ***CalendarDayPart*** in the list of ***DayParts*** for the chosen day **AND** every other day that is either 16 before or after the selected date.

### EXAMPLE:

***BlockDays*** is the List of Calendar Days

```
'' get the desired calendar day from the month's list of calendar days
Dim cDay As CalendarDay = BlockDays.ElementAt(25)

''change calDay to have one more parts and not defualt value
cDay.TotalDayParts += 1

''manually create CalendarDayPart 
Dim cDayPart As New CalendarDayPart With {.CalendarID = cal.CalendarID,
                                        .DayPartID = 0,
                                        .CreatedDate = Now,
                                        .OverlayTypeID = spDay.OverlayTypeID,
                                        .PartPriority = spDay.InjectPriority,
                                        .DayID = cDay.DayID,
                                        .ColorCode = spDay.InjectColorCode
                                        }

''increase value of all day parts with same priority or higher
For Each cPart In (From p In cDay.DayParts Where p.PartPriority >= spDay.InjectPriority Select p).ToList
    cPart.PartPriority += 1
Next

''inject CalendarDayPart part at specified priority 
cDay.DayParts.Insert(spDay.InjectPriority - 1, cDayPart)
''THE ABOVE LINE IS THE PROBLEM
```

Please note the last line is the problem.  The **cDay.DayParts.Insert** is the exact moment the ***CalendarDayPart*** is inserted in the the list called ***DayParts*** for the specifically (and single) selected element from the "parent" list.

**The problem** is that if I add a watch in the code to any parent element whose index value in the parent list is either 16 greater or fewer than the selected index (set like this: *BlockDays.ElementAt(25)*) then those additional elements also have a ***CalendarDayPart*** added to their ***DayParts*** list

I have been banging my head against a wall here, I have tried creating new objects for the lists and that does not solve the problem.

Using a watch/breakpoint I can confirm that the last line of code in the example where the insert happens is the exact moment that element and the others get the inserted ***CalendarDayPart*** added to the ***DayParts*** List.

I hope I made this clear enough.

### QUESTION

Can someone help me figure out why the list(t).Insert method is effecting more than the single element that is calling the method?

Thanks

### ANSWER

I had to add the folling .toList to the creation of the CalendarDayPart as it uses a 16 item list of days to build out the month.

```
Dim CurrentDay As New CalendarDay With {.CalendarID = rd.CalendarID,
                                        .DayID = rd.DayID,
                                        .DayOrder = d,
                                        .CreatedDate = Now,
                                        .TotalDayParts = rd.TotalDayParts,
                                        .DayParts = rd.DayParts.ToList, ''have to use toList to force new items, not just pointer to existing list in rotation day
                                        .UpdatedDate = Now}
```

Notice the rd.DayParts.ToList
this is the rotationDay's DayParts.  If I had rd.DayParts it references the same day parts.

Comment: Can you show more code context? Is there a loop somewhere filling up all of these `DayParts` lists from the parent item? Do you create a new `cDayPart` every time? To get where I'm eventually going...do you understand the difference between `by value` and `by reference`?

Comment: thanks cory, the BlockDays are passed into this function reference.  and the cDayPart is "newed" each time it gets called and I have set breakpoint to confirm that this entire function only gets called once.  It would be tough to provide more code context because the context is large.  I had the same thought as you and that is why i set the watches and breakpoints to confirm where exactly the values change.  The insert statement only gets called once and that is exactly where the watch shows the other values increasing.

Comment: the day parts are pulled from database records based on a shared ID so there is no loop creating the dayparts.  However I see where you are going and I agree, I feel like there is an overlap of variables/values but I can not find it.

Comment: I suspect that the DayParts list is not unique to each cDay. That is, some cDay objects share a common DayParts list. Take a close look at code the creates or sets the DayParts lists.

Comment: you were both right.  The calendar is based on a 16 day shift rotation for fire fighters.  The original block days reuse a 16 day list to build the full month and as a result the DayParts reference the same parts every 16 days.  I had to add a .toList when creating a new cDayPart and copying the DayParts from the base 16 day rotation.  Add this as an answer and I will accept it